# How to align text at multiple specific places?

Tags: luatex, texlive, gregorio

Up till yesterday I have always done all my layout in InDesign.  However, there are places where this makes things tedious, so I'm trying to see how to do all the hard work in tex.

In my tex file I include a staff of chant generated by gregorio.

Now, under the staff there needs to be several lines of verses all aligned in multiple specific places.  It also needs the ability to break across pages.

I've tried loading the `amsmath` package and using `\align` environments, but aside from not working on more than one "line" or "equation", that has other unwanted effects.

Here is an image of what I *want* to have in the end ([image from here](http://gregobase.selapa.net/chant.php?id=457)):

[image: gregorio chant block]

Now, in my tex file, I already have the chant and several lines of text:

```
\includescore{LitanyOfSaints_1Kyrie.tex}
Fí- li  Re- démptor     múndi,  Dé-us,  mi- seré-re nóbis. \\
Spí-    ri- tus     Sán-    cte             Dé- us, mi- seré-re nóbis. \\ 
Sáncta  Trí-    ni- tas,    únus    Dé- us, mi- seré-re nóbis. \\
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use, `tabular`, or `tabbing`.....

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic here, because it's very specific to Gregorio and its way of inputting data.

Comment: But it's also specific to the tex that gregorio outputs.  The solution could be something to be solved in the outputted tex file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to align the lyrics lines among themselves, using the tabular environment should be enough. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Fí- li  Re- démptor     múndi,   & Dé-us,    & mi- seré-re nóbis. \\
Spí-    ri- tus     Sán-    cte  &  Dé- us,  & mi- seré-re nóbis. \\
Sáncta  Trí-    ni- tas,    únus & Dé- us,   & mi- seré-re nóbis. \\  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Notice the use of the fontspec package to deal with the stress marks (this should be compiled with lualatex).

Now, if you need to align the lyrics with the music notes too, I suggest that you have a look at the example at the end of page 85 [of the documentation of MusiXTeX package](http://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf).

Comment: There is another problem - that the first line of text under the staff is done by Gregorio and is inside the included .tex file.  It's not so easy to get it into `tabular`.

Comment: That `MusiXTeX` - I didn't know about it.  That has nothing to do with `gregorio`, right?  `gregorio` writes the chant out a different way.  I guess it doesn't make sense to use them together.

Comment: When I use `tabular` in the example, it indents the text under the staff.  How do I keep it from indenting?

Comment: Ah - that last tidbit - I used `\begin{flushleft}` around the text.  You can't wrap the gregorio tex include though!

Comment: @BGM -- i don't know `gregorio`, but it *is* a function provided by `tabbing` to set and "kill" a line establishing "tab stops".  perhaps you could use the first line (already included and not under your control) as a "template" for setting the stops.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was finally able to contact the authour of the original chant that I was wanting to reproduce.

He said that he first exported the chant from gregorio and got a look at it, then he used `tabular` (credit to Randall who answered that, too) to visually align the text up to the chant.  He inserted spaces in the chant where necessary.

And here I thought there was some wiz-bang secret!
This is the final answer, but I'm going to accept Randall's answer for suggesting `tabular` and providing the example.